# URL of edit page like Stack Overflow edit page

Tags: url, database-design

I noted that on Stack Overflow when editing a question or answer it opens the same URL with different ids. These ids are continually ids, for example:

1. `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1232345/edit`
2. `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1232346/edit`

1<sup>st</sup> URL is to edit a question, but the 2<sup>nd</sup> is to edit an answer.

How can I implement something like that? I thought there are two tables, one for questions and another for answers, so how can I put continually ids in two different tables?
What is the idea behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, both questions and answers are in one table (on Stack Overflow) named Posts, with column PostType (1 (question) or 2 (answer))